# Rounding Error When Converting Double to Char

Tags: c, char, int, double

I've been tasked with recreating printf in C using no external libraries. I'm attempting to implement %f functionality with a precision of 6 decimal places. So basically, if I pass 15.2554 into the printf function "15.255400" should be printed. Instead, what's printed is "15.255399." My code to find the decimal places is implemented as such:

```
print_function(double input){

  int i = 0;
  int temp;
  double temp_dub;
  char temp_char;

  temp = (int)input;

  temp_dub = input - temp;

  while (i < 6){

    temp_dub = temp_dub * 10;
    temp = (int) temp_dub;
    temp_char = (char) (temp+48)

    write(1,&temp_char,1);
    i++;

    temp_dub -= (int) temp_dub;
  }

  return;
}
```

Can anyone please illuminate me as to why I'm unable to get the trailing zeros and instead this number is just slightly below my input of 15.554?

Comment: `C` and `C++` are **different** languages. One tag is clearly not needed.

Comment: Your function displays garbage for 15.554. Make sure you posted the right code snippet.

Comment: This code could work in C or C++ unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: DYZ. This exact code works on my machine and prints out 15.255399 instead of 15.255400

Comment: At the very least, you code does not print any periods. Check again. It _would_ work, if you changed it as suggested in the answer by Ari0nhh. (48 should be added to `temp_char`, not to `temp`.)

Comment: Right, I'm showing the part of the code that prints the decimal as it's the pertinent part of the program. I did make the changes suggested by Ari0nhh and unfortunately I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: Although code may work in C and C++, the best answer does vary depending on C or C++.

Comment: `temp = (int)input;` is UB for values outside the `int` range.  This code fails for about 40% of all `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value `15.2554` is not representable as a binary64 (IEEE-754 `double`). You can see it if you print the input with enough digits:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
// I took the liberty to implement Ari0nhh's changes here
void print_function(double input){
  int i = 0;
  int temp;
  double temp_dub;
  char temp_char;

  temp = (int)input;
  temp_dub = input - temp;

  while (i < 6){
    temp_dub = temp_dub * 10;
    temp = (int) temp_dub;
    temp_char = (char) (temp + 48);
    write(1,&temp_char,1);
    i++;
    temp_dub -= (int) temp_dub;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  double input;
  if(argc != 2){
    fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s float\n",argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // checks omitted
  input = strtod(argv[1],NULL);
  printf("INP %.20g\n",input);
  print_function(input);
  putchar('\n');
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

You will see that `15.2554` prints as `15.255399999999999849`. So you need to round manually here, sorry.

Comment: Okay this makes sense, but then how would I be able to round if I'm trying to write the printf function myself? How would I know that I'm receiving only 4 places of precision and need to round the last two if the binary shows more precision?

Comment: You cannot, that information is lost. On thing you can do is to check the 7th digit and round always (in whatever rounding mode you prefer).

Comment: Thank you for answering and not nit-picking about whether or not I tagged things correctly!